$\lim_{r\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\ r^n(w-z_0)^n$
I'm recently working with complex power series an I stumble across a sentence that I'm not capable to fully understand

Given a complex power series like
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
that has $R>0$ as radius of convergence: meaning that for every $\zeta\in D(z_0,R) :=\{z\in \Bbb C: |z-z_0|<R\}$ the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\zeta-z_0)^n$$
nothing in general can be said about the
convergence of a power series at the points on the circle of its disk of convergence.

Even if for a fixed $w\in \partial D(z_0,R)$
$$\lim_{r\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\ r^n(w-z_0)^n\tag{1}\label{eq}$$
exists finite, it does not follow that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\ (w-z_0)^n\tag{2}\label{eq_2}$$
converges

my question is why expression $\eqref{eq}$ is meaningful in let us think that series $\eqref{eq_2}$ could be convergent?
I thought that $\eqref{eq_2}$ is convergent if
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(w-z_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\alpha^n$$
is finite, where $\alpha\in \Bbb C$ such that $|\alpha| = R$, as said before in general we haven't much information about this convergence. I think the flow of thoughts is trying to add some information that led us to think that convergence is possible, here $\eqref{eq}$ takes place and
$$\lim_{r\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\ r^n(w-z_0)^n=\lim_{r\to R^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\ r^n\alpha^n$$
here since is said that convergence is satisfied a valuable information is $a_n(r\alpha)^n\to 0$. Here is the piece I think I'm missing; why could I be driven to think that this helps convergence in $z=w$?

Thank you for the help!

We have $$\lim_{r\to 1^-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nr^n=\lim_{r\to 1^-}{1\over 1+r}={1\over 2}$$ However the series $\sum (-1)^n$ is divergent

@RyszardSzwarc So in your example we're considering $\sum(-1)^n z^n$ we're trying to say what happen for $z=1$ and even though what you highlighted above converges, our series is far away for convergence. A less mysterious now I should say!

See this
